Pyramid Scheme on an infinite Lattice
A set of shrewd investors, each with a single gold coin in hand, arrange themselves in a lattice of the form $\mathbb{Z}^I$, where $I$ is any index set (finite or infinite, countable or uncountable). At the count of three, all of them will simultaneously pass their single coin to any one of their orthogonal neighbours.
Can they devise a strategy, such that everyone ends up with strictly more money than before?
(The answer to this may, of course, depend on the index set $I$.)
To be precise about the terms used here: $\mathbb{Z}^I$ denotes the set of $I$-tuples of integers. Two such tuples are orthogonal neighbours, if there is a single coordinate in which they differ by $\pm 1$, while agreeing everywhere else. Everyone involved knows their position in the lattice and they may strategize before this procedure takes place.
Have fun solving this! :)

Can I assume the axiom of choice?

@Lucenaposition Yes! (My solution does so as well, but I would be really interested if that can be avoided somehow)


 Finite case ($n$ dimensions): No
 Proof: Suppose we look at an $n$-dimensional box of side length $x$. This box will contain $x^n$ investors and $x^n$ coins. After the coins are passed, each investor ends up with at least $2$ coins. So there must be at least $2x^n$ coins in that $n$-dimensional box. We then consider the $n$-dimensional box of side length $x+2$ around it. Only investors in that box can pass their gold coin to a person in the $n$-dimensional box of side length $x$. So there are at most $(x+2)^n$ gold coins in the $n$-dimensional box of side length $x$ after each one has passed a coin to the other one. For sufficiently large $x$, we have $(x+2)^n<2x^n$.


 Infinite case (assuming the axiom of choice):
 Let $X$ be the number of dimensions. Assume $X$ is an initial ordinal. $|X^a|=|X|$ for all positive integers $a$. Since $|X\times\aleph_0|=|X|$, there is a bijection with $X$ and $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}X^n$.
 Note that in the well-ordering of $X$ (which has order-type $X$), every proper initial segment has cardinality less than $|X|$.
 Consider the set of investors that have only finitely many coordinates that are non-zero. This set has cardinality $|X|$ so we can well-order it with order-type $X$. Let this set be $\{A_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in x}$
 For each investor $A_\alpha$ with $\alpha$ ascending, we choose $2$ investors to give gold coins to it. Since we have only told $2\times\alpha$ investors who to give their gold coins to, and $|2\times\alpha|<|X|$, and each investor has $|X|$ neighbours, we can choose $2$ investors who are neighbours of $A_\alpha$ and assign them to give gold to $A_\alpha$. This is possible as $|2\times\alpha+2|<|X|$. The unassigned investors can gives coins to anyone.
 So all the investors with finitely many non-zero coordinates get at least 2 coins.
 Call two investors close if their coordinates differ in a finite number of places. Closeness is an equivalence relation. For each equivalence class of investors, the strategy above can be repeated so every investor ends up with at least $2$ coins.


This looks sensible so far! But what is the strategy for all the investors that don't live in the direct sum $\mathbb{Z}^{(I)}$?

As an aside: rot13(Vs gur vaqrk frg $V$ vf n pneqvany, gur vairfgbef va gur qverpg fhz unir n zhpu fvzcyre fgengrtl gung rira cnlf rnpu bs gurz $V$ pbvaf.) Can you see what that may be?
